# Javascript set minimum scroll ability

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrollbar

I have a website and I want there to be a minimum to how much the user can scroll up and down.
Meaning that no matter little the content of the page is, the scroll ability should never go below this given amount.

How do I set that in Javascript?

Comment: not javascript, but you can give your body or container element min-height

Comment: Did you try to set html,body height to 100% - you could add a padding bottom to the body which would be your minimum scroll abiliity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

CSS:

```
HTML {
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    padding-top: 200px;
}
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.body.scrollIntoView(true);
    return;
}
```

Comment: found some here: http://www.reignwaterdesigns.com/ad/tidbits/hacks/minimum_height_in_css.shtml

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson I had to fix my code, the original worked only in IE. Now it's using `padding` instead of `margin`, and seems to work at least in IE9+, Chrome and FF. Opera seems not to know `scrollIntoView()`.